# Reading serial data written on socket in android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a device which writes some bytes of variable length on socket. I want to read the same in my android application. Device outputs the bytes on socket from its input which is connected to another device via serial port.

I tried using BufferedReader, DataInputStream ,but with niether I could find a perfect way to read bytes of variable length. I also think encoding may be another issue. With DataInputStream I tried reading byte by byte but then its a bad idea as its very expensive. With BufferedReader I tried reading characters and then converting characters to String and then fetching bytes from the String. I got wrong bytes, may be due to encoding issues.

Please help me in finding the good way to do so.

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am sorry for not adding an example but its usual socket programming in which usual ways (as mentioned in the question) does not help me much. Anyways currently I am in need of some help and do not have system. I will add the examples of what I tried soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `DataInputStream` wrapped around a `BufferedInputStream`. The `DataInputStream` gives you the API you need, and the `BufferedInputStream` the performance.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Ok, that is something nice. So I read byte by byte but read it from buffered reader